# I have an old Dell computer but the charger does not work

Tags: laptop, usb, battery, charging, usb-c

I have an old dell computer that has the regular charging socket malfunctioning.
I have been trying to find if I can use a charger that has USB C and then use an adapter on the laptop to convert USB A female to USB C female and charge it.

Can anyone tell me if this would work?

Answer (score 2):

This absolutely will not work.

Just because *some* laptops can charge over USB C does not mean *every* laptop can be charged over USB A.

No laptop can change via their USB A sockets. USB A does not support bi-directional power. It can only output power *from* your laptop.

A USB C to A adaptor will do absolutely nothing to make it possible to charge your laptop.

Get your charging socket repaired by a qualified technician.